# DotNetNuke site keeps redirecting back to upgrade wizard

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I just upgraded from 6.02.08 to 09 and every time I load the page, it just goes back to the upgrade wizard. The upgrade says it works fine, but then when I click *click here to access your site*, it just takes me back to the upgrade wizard.

If I change auto-update to false, then I get the *under construction* page.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for this behavior is difficulty connecting to the database.  Check the connection string in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

So oddly enough, I just dropped in the 7.0 upgrade files and ran through that upgrade and it's now working fine. I know it wasn't a database connection issue, because I never modified the connection string. Strange, but lucky!